# Matlab Numerical Solver: Solving Second Order differential Equation

Tags: matlab, modeling, differential-equations

I am truly sorry that I could not provide details for the exact equation that I am working with. It is a very complicated second-order differential equation in the form similar to this:

[image]
where function `a(z) ~ e(z) and g(z)` are given. `p` is constant.

I also have the boundary conditions.

Is it possible to solve `f(z)` with the help of matlab?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

## EDIT

Here is how I defined my function. `a1 ~ g1` and `fna ~ fng` are defined and stored in `Gdata.mat`:

```
function xp=myfunc(t,p)
% x =  [d2f df f df2 f2 d2f2]
% xp = [df d2f f2 df2 d3f d2f2]
load GData
xp=zeros(6,1); % [f df d2f f2 df2]
               % f
fprintf('%d\n',length(xp));
fprintf('%d\n',length(p));
xp(1) = x(2);  % df
xp(2) = x(1);  % d2f
               % f2
xp(4) = x(4);  % df2
xp(6) = x(6);  % d2f2
xp(5) = (...
        b1(t)*p(3) + b(t)*p(2) + ...
        c1(t)*p(3)^3 + 3*fnc(t)*p(3)^2*p(2) + ...
        d1(t)*p(3)^5 + 5*fnd(t)*p(3)^4*p(2) + ...
        e1(t)*p(3)^7 + 7*fne(t)*x(3)^6*p(2) - ...
        f1(t)*p(2)*p(3) + f1(t)*p(1)*p(3) + f1(t)*p(2)^2 - ...
        g1(t)*p(4) - fng(t)*p(6) + ...
        q*p(2) - a1(t)*p(1)...
        ) * 1/(fna(t));
```

then I called:

```
[TEMP,POL] = ode45('odesolver',[0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0]);
```

## EDIT2

```
function dp=odesolver(t,p)
% dp = [df d2f d3f]
syms x;
load BData;
load GData;
dp=zeros(3,1); % [f df d2f]

A = interp1(t_data,At,t);
B = interp1(t_data,Bt,t);
C = interp1(t_data,Ct,t);
D = interp1(t_data,Dt,t);
E = interp1(t_data,Et,t);
F = interp1(t_data,Ft,t);
G = interp1(t_data,Gt,t);

A1 = interp1(t_data,A1t,t);
B1 = interp1(t_data,B1t,t);
C1 = interp1(t_data,C1t,t);
D1 = interp1(t_data,D1t,t);
E1 = interp1(t_data,E1t,t);
F1 = interp1(t_data,F1t,t);
G1 = interp1(t_data,G1t,t);

dp(1) = p(2); % f'
dp(2) = p(3); % f''
dp(3) = (...
        B1*p(3) + B*p(2) + ...
        C1*p(3)^3 + 3*C*p(3)^2*p(2) + ...
        D1*p(3)^5 + 5*D*p(3)^4*p(2) + ...
        E1*p(3)^7 + 7*E*p(3)^6*p(2) - ...
        F1*p(2)*p(3) + F*p(1)*p(3) + F*p(2)^2 - ...
        2*G1*p(2)*p(1) + 2*G*p(3)*p(1) + 2*G*p(2)*p(2) + ...
        q*p(2) - A1*p(1)) * 1/(A);
```

Comment: Thank you David. What about in the case of second order? it looks like `ode45` only take one boundary condition.(?) Thanks.

Comment: I found an online tutorial on solving second order using `ode45`, but here I also have a first derivative of `f^2` and a integral term of `f^2` how do I deal with these? Thanks.

Comment: You need to convert your second-order ode into two first order ODEs, which you can solve with `ode45`. See http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66301-solve-a-second-order-differential-equation for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thank you @am304 , I followed https://www.math.purdue.edu/academic/files/courses/2005spring/MA266/ode45.pdf and was able to do second-order ODE. My questions now is that my equation involves first derivative of `f^2` and an integral term of `f^2` I don't know how to deal with these. Thanks

Comment: To get round the integral, differentiate your ode once more to get a third-order ode and convert it to 3 first-order odes you can solve with `ode45` using the same technique. I guess for the derivative of `f^2`, you just need to add more states to your vector, so that you would have something like `dy = yourfcn(t,y)` with `y = [d2f; df; f; df2; f2]` i.e. the second and first derivative of `f`, `f`, the first derivative of `f^2` and `f^2`.

Comment: @am304 Thank you for your suggestion. I am still lost. I have update my attempt in the original post. I am currently getting `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` error. Thanks.

Comment: The problem comes from you indexing your variables with `t`. You can't do that. `t` is avaraible itself, which can take any value in your time interval, it's not an index you can use for your other variables. If your variables are dependent on `t`, then you need to do some linear interpolation using `interp1` to find out the correct value corresponding to each value of `t` based on your data. See http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/78456-how-can-i-use-discrete-time-data-instead-of-functions-for-solving-equations-using-ode45 as an example.

Comment: Thank you so much.The code seem to work now but not providing correct solution. So in this case, do I need 5 boundary conditions then? for `d2f; df; f; df2; f2`? Thanks.

Comment: You need as many initial conditions as you have of states in your vector. Double-check your equations and code and make sure they're both correct. It's easy to make a sign mistake and/or get the states muddled up when writing the differential equations.

Comment: I think your states are wrong, please double-check. See my edited answer.

Comment: Derivative of `f^2` is `2*f*df` (df=derivative of f).

Comment: @David That is so true....... I have made another update to the original post under EDIT2. Does that look more reasonable? But is there an other way to deal with the integral part? If I take another derivative, I will need an other boundary condition then.(I'm not sure I have boundary condition for f''(x0) ) Thanks.

Comment: The integral is a definite integral with constant bounds, so it is a constant, with derivative zero. Maybe you will need to use some kind of iterative technique or solve a system of equations where the unknowns are a series of values of `f`.

Comment: I understand that the derivative reduce to zero, but the equation would become third order, and it would require another boundary condition....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on the discussion and edited question:

There are several obstacles in using `ode45` to solve your differential equation, but none of them are a showstopper:

- **Second order ODE**: convert into 2 first-order odes you can solver with `ode45`, as in [this question](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66301-solve-a-second-order-differential-equation).
- **Integral term**: differentiate your equation to get rid of it. You will end up with a third-order differential equation, which you need to convert into 3 first-order equations using the same technique as above
- **Derivative of the square of the function to integrate**: add additional states to your `ode` function to allow solving with `ode45`
- **Time-dependent variables**: you can't just directly use your time variable to index into your time-dependent variables. You need to do a linear interpolation to for each value of `t` using your time-dependent data to get the corresponding values of your variables, as in [this other question](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/78456-how-can-i-use-discrete-time-data-instead-of-functions-for-solving-equations-using-ode45).

So your code should look something like this (I have assumed that you have a common time vector for all your time-dependent data in your `GData` file, this may not be the case, you may have a different time vector for each variable - adjust the code if necessary; either way make sure your time-dependent data is defined on the time interval on which your are calling `ode45`):

```
function dx=myfunc(t,x)
% x =  [d2f df f df2 f2 d2f2]
% dx = [d3f d2f df d2f2 df2 d3f2]
load GData % I assume this contains b1, b, c1, etc... *and* the corresponding time vector, say t_data
dx=zeros(6,1); % [d3f d2f df d2f2 df2 d3f2]

fprintf('%d\n',length(dx));
fprintf('%d\n',length(x));
dx(1) = x(2);  % double-check!!
dx(2) = x(1);  % double-check!!
               % double-check!!
dx(4) = x(4);  % double-check!!
dx(6) = x(6);  % double-check!!

B1 = interp1(t_data,b1,t);
B = interp1(t_data,b,t);
C1 = interp1(t_data,c1,t);
% etc... for the other variables

dx(5) = (...
        B1*p(3) + B*p(2) + ...
        C1*p(3)^3 + 3*FNC*p(3)^2*p(2) + ...
        D1*p(3)^5 + 5*FND*p(3)^4*p(2) + ...
        E1*p(3)^7 + 7*FNE*x(3)^6*p(2) - ...
        F1*p(2)*p(3) + F1*p(1)*p(3) + F1*p(2)^2 - ...
        G1*p(4) - FNG*p(6) + ...
        q*p(2) - A1*p(1)...
        ) * 1/(FNA); % double-check!!
```